# RuntimeException: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3145776 at offset 236

Tags: android, parcelable, android-proguard

I want to pass a parcelable object over to another activity. These objects contain a bitmap, and in some cases I get the error: RuntimeException: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3145776 at offset 236. Here is the code:

```
_profilePicture = (Bitmap) in.readValue(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
```

Weird thing is, that it doesn't happen with all objects like suggested in other StackOverflow answers. I pasted this piece of code somewhere in my proguard file (the one for optimization, not the "proguard-android.txt" one):

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}
```

It doesn't work though.

Comment: don't pass Bitmaps between activities. Pass a reference and load them in each activity separately. It probably works "sometimes" because some objects are of a smaller size and a Parcelable actually has a max size. (the answer is nothing to do with proguard)

Comment: Ok, I didnt thought of that, thank you

Comment: The part about bitmap is 100% right, pass Uri, load them independently in every place with static caching, if necessary. Don't use `Bitmap.class.getClassLoader()`, this will use system classloader, and system classloader does not load *your* custom classes. Use `SomeCustomParcelableYouWrote.class.getClassloader()`.